# Suggestions for leg support and edge guard for countertop

Tags: trim, support, countertops

I need to cut open some part of the wood countertop to allow for stacking up the washer and dryer.

[image]
[image]

For support, how can I add a leg (blue) to support the remaining counter top. I am thinking it has to be extended outward. Much like an extensible cloth hanger pole for closets. Does something like that exist as countertop leg? Another suggestion that serves the same purpose is welcome.

For aesthetics, I wonder if there is any edge guard that is recommended to cover the vertical wood part (green) and maybe around an inch along the top surface of the countertop. I would like to know what the item is called.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The stuff for the green bit is **edge banding**. You can also use thin strips of the laminate that the counter is topped with if you can get it, or have some stashed, so that it matches better.

The usual approach to the blue bit is to simply put a sheet of plywood there, parallel to the washer/dryer beside it - or just put a cabinet there, rather than having an open hole.

A cleat is screwed to both the countertop and the vertical plywood to make the joint.

Comment: What are the steps and material involved to build a cabinet with sliding drawers to replace the open hole? And can I build that *after* I put the washer and dryer in place? Thanks.

Comment: Sure, you can slide one in later. Generally, even if "how to build a cabinet" is not a mystery, it still makes more sense to just buy one pre-built that fits. They are a commodity item, and it's hard to compete with a factory production line if you value your time at all. Discards from remodeling are even cheaper or free. Be sure you allow for access to that outlet, if you are going to need that. If you feel a need to tilt at windmills, I suggest getting a book on making kitchen cabinets from your local library.

Answer (score 1):

For the area in green, the exposed edge that you cut out will have to be sealed. I recommend using primer then paint. [90 degree aluminum trim](https://www.lowes.com/pd/Steelworks-8-ft-x-1-in-Aluminum-Solid-Angle/3058171) could be used for a really nice finish.

For the area in blue, the easiest thing to do would be to support the ledge with a big 90 degree shelf bracket. If you plan on putting a lot of weight on the ledge, you are going to need to build a leg for it.